# .toFixed isnt working when trying to output number

Tags: javascript

I need the output of price to be  2 or 3 decimals.

```
setInterval(function(){
 $.ajax({

    url : 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/chainlink/',
    type : 'GET',
    data : {
        'numberOfWords' : 10
    },
    dataType:'json',
    success : function(data) {
       price = data[0].price_usd;
        document.getElementById('link_price').innerHTML = price.toFixed(3);

    },
    error : function(request,error)
    {
        console.log('Error by getting the AGI price');
    }
  })
}, 3000);
```

but i get an error doing this

```
(index):170 Uncaught TypeError: price.toFixed is not a function
    at Object.success ((index):170)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
```

I want to keep this simple just like that so i dont know why it isnt working.

I also tried

```
price = data[0].price_usd;
price-usd = price.toFixed(3);
            document.getElementById('link_price').innerHTML = price-usd;
```

Which basically gives me the same error as i posted above

This version works but it gives me to many decimals

```
setInterval(function(){
 $.ajax({

    url : 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/chainlink/',
    type : 'GET',
    data : {
        'numberOfWords' : 10
    },
    dataType:'json',
    success : function(data) {
       price = data[0].price_usd;
        document.getElementById('link_price').innerHTML = price;

    },
    error : function(request,error)
    {
        console.log('Error by getting the AGI price');
    }
  })
}, 3000);
```

Comment: `price-usd` is invalid anyway ... that's "price minus usd" .. is `price` a Number?  if not, then that's the issue - hint: it's a string

Comment: @JaromandaXyes print gives me a number, i updated the code

Comment: `price = data[0].price_usd;` should be a Number in the first place. You can cast like `price = +data[0].price_usd;`, but I would change initial value.

Comment: @StackSlavethis works dude i just added the +

Comment: @redbull - no, that API gives you a String for `price_usd`

Answer (score -1):

`.toFixed()` only formats/accepts numbers as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed). You need to convert to number type:

```
price = parseInt(data[0].price_usd);
price-usd = price.toFixed(3);
```

or

```
price = Number(data[0].price_usd);
price-usd = price.toFixed(3);
```